# Freeze when app is resumed and a secondary application view was created and closed before

Tags: uwp

In my C# UWP application, I create a secondary application view and I have run into a problem related to the application life cycle. Below is a list of steps that cause this issue:

- A secondary ApplicationView is created from the main view.
- When it is closed by the user, the Consolidated event fires and the handler calls Window.Current.Close() at the end.
- The main view is minimized causing the application EnteredBackground and Suspending event to fire.
- When the view is restored, its UI is frozen.

So far I have found that adding any event handler (even an empty one) to the LeavingBackground event of the application object causes this behavior if the secondary view has been opened and closed before. Using the Resuming event however works fine. Unfortunately, I use the appcenter library which registers for the LeavingBackground event. I have tried to find out if the issue might be caused by an incomplete destruction of the secondary view but even a XAML page with no code behind, no event handlers or bindings and just using the platform controls shows this issue. Only if the second page is just a single button it often (but not always) works correctly. I can also see the same issue with the MultipleViews universal sample if I add a few more controls to the secondary page. So I suspect that this might be a platform issue. I see this issue on Windows 1809 and also the 19H1 preview. Anybody know a fix or workaround?

Comment: I have tested with [MultipleViews](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews) code sample with your steps, However I could not reproduce the issue. Could share a sample that could repro?

Comment: Yes, the issue does notrRepro with the default MultipleViews sample. A Version that causes this freeze is located here: [link](https://github.com/lhak/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews/cs)

Comment: I could reproduce your issue,  I will report this to related team. And I found If remove setting page's xaml content the issue will disappear.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Yep, I tried create new project and use `ApplicationViewSwitcher` ( not `ViewLifetimeControl` ), it works well, And I have reported `ViewLifetimeControl` issue to product team.

Comment: The issue is not related to the ViewLifetimeControl class in the sample. I can easily reproduce the same issue without it if I call Window.Current.Close() when the secondary window (containing the XAML code from the sample) is consolidated and I register the app for the lifecycle events mentioned above. If you have a working sample, please post the code somewhere.

Comment: OK, I will try to invoke `Window.Current.Close()` when the secondary window is consolidated.

Comment: Any update? This is really a serious issue!

Comment: Yep, I escalated this issue, if there is any update I will post below.